# Get EntityMilestone fields values?

Tags: apex, trigger

I'm coding a trigger on case and I'm using this query to get some data fields information from **CaseMilestone** entity:

```
Select caseid,MilestoneTypeId,CompletionDate,ElapsedTimeInMins,IsCompleted,IsViolated, 
                         StartDate,TargetDate,TargetResponseInHrs,ElapsedTimeInHrs,
                         TargetResponseInMins,TimeSinceTargetInMins,TimeRemainingInMins
                        from CaseMilestone where caseid= :c.id
```

I need to use other fields from a new entity **EntityMilestone**:

- ActualElapsedTimeInDays
- StoppedTimeInDays

How can i link these 2 entities?

Comment: The object reference for [`EntityMilestone`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_entitymilestone.htm) says "Milestones on cases use the CaseMilestone object type". Can you elaborate on how you're trying to use this object?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! i'd like to use those 2 fields inside my query! Which is the best practice to link them?

Comment: I'm not an expert in entitlement management, but the documentation suggests that unless you're using Work Orders or Field Service Lightning, you can't use that object. Hopefully a Service Cloud/Entitlement expert can chime in here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are working on Cases with Milestones then the appropriate object is  [`CaseMilestone`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfFieldRef.meta/sfFieldRef/salesforce_field_reference_CaseMilestone.htm) which is available from API version 18.0 or later.

Where as [EntityMilestone](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_entitymilestone.htm) Represents a required step in a customer support process on a work order. The Salesforce user interface uses the term “object milestone.” This object is available in API version 37.0 and later.

And EntitlyMilestone is not related to Case.

Comment: i'm doing this query: SELECT ActualElapsedTimeInDays , CaseId FROM CaseMilestone WHERE isDeleted = false ORDER BY Id DESC NULLS LAST